# Can Ansible provision plain text files on MS Windows? Is this supported?

Tags: windows, ansible

I recently started targeting MS Windows with my Ansible scripts. Now I noticed that most of the Ansible modules will not deal with MS Windows newlines. So for example if you use  `win_copy` with `content` you can only provision text files with one line. Multiple line text files are not supported. For example `win_copy` below will create a file with one line with contents `line1 line2`.

```
- name: Create install file
  ansible.windows.win_copy:
    dest: whatever.txt
    content: |
      line1
      line2
```

Is it possible somehow to tell Ansible that the target is MS Windows? So that it will provision these type of files correctly?

I also tried

```yaml
- name: Create install file
  ansible.windows.win_copy:
    dest: whatever.txt
    content: "{{ lines | join('\r\n') }}"
```

Or should the control node be MS Windows for this to work correctly?

Also the `win_template` module does not work. For example a template

```yaml
{%- for key, value in tomcat_install_config.items() %}
{{ key }}={{ value }}
{%- endfor %}
```

will put everything on one line. The `newline_sequence` property does not seem to do much in this regards

```
- name: Create install file
  win_template:
    src: java.properties.j2
    dest: "{{ tomcat_install_config_path }}"
    newline_sequence: \r\n
```

As a workaround I think I will try template below:

```
{%- for key, value in tomcat_install_config.items() %}
{{ key }}={{ value }}{{ "\r\n" }}
{%- endfor %}
```

This does create a multi-line text file.

Comment: You can probably just say \r at the end of eact line in content: but honestly, I'd just use a template every time. The problem isn't win_copy, I'm pretty sure the problem is just that most sane text editors put only a \n in yaml files, trying to make them not would get confusing fast for the editors and tools like linters. I'd just use a template every time.

Comment: \r at the end also doesn't help

Comment: As it turns out, win_template also puts everything one line. So basically I think the control node needs to be MS Windows but I cannot test that.